# How to 'conda activate base' after accidentally using 'conda deactivate' while in (base) environment?

Tags: conda, config, environment, radix

My problem: when opening a MacOS terminal, (base) environment is missing. I'm trying to get (base) back so I can do `conda activate <another venv>`. But, it says `zsh: command not found: conda`. Alternatively, I could go back to Anaconda Navigator or VS code to open terminal via the respective venvs, but that's too much of a trouble sometimes.

Back-tracking a little: (base) disappeared when I accidentally did a `conda deactivate` while in (base) environment.

I've tried various solutions on a new terminal like:

```
source /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

or even replicating what happens in VS code:

```
source /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate
```

which both works great to get (base) back in the current terminal, but (base) disappears again when I open a new terminal.

Also tried:

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base true
```

while in (base) env but seems like nothing happened.

Could someone please guide me on how to change PATH etc so I don't have to repeatedly type the lines above every time I open a new terminal?

---

### Additional Info

**`conda info` Output**

[image: Conda info output]

Comment: Please check `conda info` to verify active environment. This can happen independently of PS1 change (e.g., adding `(base)` to the shell line). What is the value of `conda config --show changeps1`?

Comment: hi @merv, please see reply below as I can't attach image here and its too long to type here.

Comment: You need to run `/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/condabin/conda init zsh`, in order for Conda to be initialized automatically when opening new `zsh` sessions. Closing as duplicate.